# New `wrong-number-of-arguments` error from `desktop-change-dir` and other commands

Tags: debugging, arguments, error

(This has started happening with other commands too, but I don't remember which.)

Previously when I ran `M-x desktop-change-dir` I would be prompted to enter a folder, whereupon Emacs would load the `.emacs-desktop` saved there. Now it loads only one file from the `.emacs-desktop`, and then gives the error below. My `.emacs` dotfile does not include the string `desktop` anywhere, and hever has, so I don't think it's responsible. It's possible I'm now on a newer version of Emacs (I use NixOS and have it upgrade things nightly). I don't know what I was on before, but lately running `M-x emacs-version` prints

```
GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.27, cairo version 1.16.0)
```

Here's the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (0 . 0) 1)
  org-roam-mode(1)
  desktop-create-buffer(208 "/home/jeff/nix/jbb-config/packages.nix" "packages.nix" nix-mode (override-global-mode global-auto-revert-mode beacon-mode org-roam-mode) 2221 (538 nil) nil nil ((tab-width . 2) (indent-tabs-mode) (buffer-display-time 24781 5953 925334 220000) (buffer-file-coding-system . undecided-unix)) ((mark-ring (538))))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/jeff/nix/jbb-config/.emacs.desktop" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3145
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jeff/nix/jbb-config/.emacs.desktop" "/home/jeff/nix/jbb-config/.emacs.desktop" t t)
  load("/home/jeff/nix/jbb-config/.emacs.desktop" t t t)
  desktop-read("/home/jeff/nix/jbb-config/")
  desktop-change-dir("~/nix/jbb-config/")
  funcall-interactively(desktop-change-dir "~/nix/jbb-config/")
  call-interactively(desktop-change-dir record nil)
  command-execute(desktop-change-dir record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "desktop-change-dir" "desk-ch")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "desktop-change-dir" "desk-ch")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Drew! That indeed did the trick. I just created a new desktop -- maybe some people have complicated ones but for me it's just a list of files to open, so it's easy to recreate.

Comment: In that case, I moved the comment to an answer, since comments can be deleted at any time. If you think this Q&A is not likely to help others, feel free to delete the question (which will also delete the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like whatever was saved in your desktop file is the problem. Some code there is calling `org-roam` and passing it an argument, but it expects *zero* arguments.

You can try bisecting your desktop file. Or you can just toss that desktop file and create a new one.

(OP confirmed that creating a new desktop file solved the problem.)